# make money substantially, considerably or gainfully

Tags: word-choice

I am going to make up a sentence.

> With a great business mind and excellent financial skills, Mary makes a lot of money every year.

Does it make sense to use an adverb to mean "a lot of" as in my revised sentence below?

> With a great business mind and excellent financial skills, Mary makes money **substantially (or considerably or gainfully)** every year.

Please give me your feedback.

Comment: The terms usually precede the noun: Mary makes a substantial amount of money every year. /Make money substantially/ is not idiomatic: make money honestly, dishonestly, properly etc. You have not put in /a lot of/.  You have put in three adverbs that don't work here. :)

Answer (score 1):

As with most English sentences, there are many ways to say something.  In this case none of the words really *work*, but here are some examples of how they may be used:

> Mark has a considerable yearly income / Mary's yearly income is considerable
>
> Mary makes a substantial amount of money each year / The amount of money she makes each year is substantial.
>
> Mary is gainfully employed.

Comment: May I bring up two more adverbs for my example? Can I say: With a great business mind and excellent financial skills, Mary makes money wisely or effectively.? Do these two adjectives work? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, those work better, although a native speaker would still use a different idiom.  "Mary manages her money wisely/effectively"